# Python extract words from a string based on a large word list

Tags: python, regex

First, I have a large word list:

```
words = ['about', 'black', 'red', ...]  # nums: 20000+
```

Then, given a string, for example:

```
s = 'blackingabouthahah'
```

I'd like to get `['black', 'about']`

I tried using regex to do this:

```
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(words))
print pattern.findall(s)
```

It works, but I'm worried about the speed and memory usage of this method.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: do you mean `pattern = re.compile('|'.join(words))`?

Comment: There is no best solution for the problem unless you specify all requirements.

Comment: I can think of an divide and conquer solution where each worker works on part of the search iteratively.

Comment: @JamesMills I can come up with several solutions, but I have no idea if they will be better than OP's solution, because he hasn't provided any details. E.g. if strings aren't long, then it might be better to generate all substrings and perform lookups in wordlist.

Comment: @Alik I agree; without *specifics* it's hard to offer up an optimal solution really!

Comment: What is the size of the string?

Comment: is `['black', 'about', 'black']` the expected output for `s = 'blackingabouthahahblackxyz'` ?

Comment: The size of `s` is the most important part of your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use a non-regex approach with `.find` using comprehension:

```
words = ['about', 'black', 'red']
s = 'blackingabouthahah'
print [x for x in words if s.find(x)>-1]
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/dHz0Cu)

This will only output unique occurrences of the terms in the list. If you need to **count** all occurrences:

```
words = ['about', 'black', 'red']
s = 'blackingabouthahahabout'
print [s.count(x) for x in words]
```

Since I do not see a difference between the first `about` and the second `about`. See [another demo](https://ideone.com/rXOt64).

Comment: your solution suffers from the same problem of not printing multiple occurrences (see my comments above). `s = 'blackingabouthahahblackxyz'` only prints `black` once.

Comment: There is no stated desire for the inclusion of repetitive elements @Pynchia. Rather, efficiency and memory optimization was the stated goal, which would suggest stopping at a match and using a generator would be much more effective.

Comment: The solution he has suggested, using `pattern.findall(s)`, prints ALL occurrences. He wants an efficient equivalent, I understand.

Comment: Right: He was worried about the memory efficiency and had no stated interest in ALL occurrences. The findall is so that way it does not break after the first match within the '|' clauses.

Comment: If the idea is to *count* the occurrences, I see an issue with my approach. If the idea is to check if the word appears in the string, I see no issue.

Comment: In fact, I have asked what the expected output would be. Got no reply yet.

Comment: @Pynchia but OP didn't state this clearly in the question. Thus, I don't understand why the answer was downvoted, not the question

Comment: I updated the answer with a *counting* solution.

Comment: @wong2: Please check my answer and please let me know if it answers your question. If not, please update your question with example input and expected output so that I could adjust the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want to print I have a solution here

```
   import re

   words = ['about', 'black', 'red',] 
   s = 'dsjhdgblackingabouthahah'

   for items in words:
      if re.search (items,s):
          print items
```

In case you want results in a new list you can try this:

```
 import re

 words = ['about', 'black', 'red',] 
 s = 'dsjhdgblackingabouthahah'
 mylist = []
 for items in words:
    if re.search (items,s):
       mylist.append( items)

 print mylist
```