# Searching a string for a large list of terms

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list of 1,500+  terms that can be multiple words long `"apple", "apple banana"`.

I want to search an input text of moderate length string (~500-1000) words for the indices of these words.

This is my current approach:

```
TERMS = ['apple', 'apple banana']

def find_indices(description):
    pattern = re.compile(f"\\b({'|'.join(TERMS)})\\b")
    return [match.span() for match in re.finditer(pattern, description)]

find_indices('apple pie') -> [(0, 5)]
```

Is there a better way to do this? My main concern is that this regex pattern will grow very large as the list increases in size.

A very closely related question with an answer that doesn't work for me: [Python extract words from a string based on a large word list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749212/python-extract-words-from-a-string-based-on-a-large-word-list)

Comment: Those numbers (1500 words, 1000 character strings) aren't really that "large".  Have you measured the time it takes with your solution ?   By the way, given that your terms are sometimes prefixes of each other, it may be necessary to sort the terms list in decreasing order of length before building the pattern(which you should compile only once, outside the function). `TERMS.sort(key=len,reverse=True)`

Comment: thank you for your comment! You are right that it's not really that large. I was concerned since I've never used a regex pattern that large before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a tree based approach might be suitable for very large texts and wordlists

We can basically create a dict of dicts that represents all the `TERMS` in a much more compressed manner, and then we can search through that more easily for every index in the main description.

```py
TERMS = ['apple', 'apple banana']

terms_tree = {}

for term in TERMS:
    node = terms_tree
    for char in term:
        if char not in node:
            node[char] = {}
        node = node[char]
    node["end"] = ''
    
main_text = 'apple pie'
all_matches = []
for i in range(len(main_text)):
    #Initial
    node = terms_tree
    match = [i, []]
    #match tree
    while i < len(main_text) and main_text[i] in node:
        node = node[main_text[i]] #traverse node
        i += 1 #continue
        if "end" in node: #check if match at end node
            match[1].append(i) #valid match
        
    if len(match[1])>0: #matches found
        all_matches.append(match)
        
print(all_matches)
```

outputs the a list having the starting index as the first term, and all the possible ending indexes that could match something from the terms list.

```
[[0, [5]]]
```

having the main text as `main_text = 'apple banana pie'` outputs

```
[[0, [5, 12]]]
```

telling us that we can match `main_text[0:5]` 'apple' or `main_text[0:12]`  'apple banana'

note - while this algorithm is more efficient, it might not be the fastest. You could consider using pypy3 to get significant speed benefits from compilation.

Comment: The trie solution is nice, thank you! Forgot all my leetcode :)